# Count unique categorical values in R

Tags: r, count

I have just started using R not long ago, as a replacement for Excel. The databases I deal with are very large and I needed a new tool to work better with them. I've managed to find a lot of answers on this website about R, which have helped me build my scripts, but was unable to find anything conclusive for one particular type of analysis.

My data looks like this:

```
Col1   Col2     Col3    ... Col50  

 M    18-24     Single  ... Employed

 F    18-24     Married ... Unemployed

 F    Under 18  Single  ... Employed
```

Usually the databases I deal with have got even 100,000 rows and 30 - 70 columns and usually there are not more than 20 unique values per column

What I want is an subset output that will give me the frequency counts for each unique 
value in each column :

```
Col1

Variable name / F / M

Frequency / 2 / 1

.....

Col50

Variable name / Employed / Un-employed

Frequency /  2 / 1
```

Can anybody at least give me a hint of what I should be looking for to count those categorical values. Do I need a special package or something? I was able to find some functions that count values, but they only refer to numerical values (like the `"table()function"`.

David Rogers

Comment: `table` works for categorical variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`table` sounds like what you want.  It will give you the number of occurrences of each value.  To easily apply table to each column we can just use lapply

```
lapply(your_data, table)
# Example use and output
lapply(mtcars, table)
```

Comment: `David` - I think what was throwing you off with `table()` is that it's best applied to vectors (whether they're categorical or not) and not data frames (esp. big ones). Using `lapply` allows you to perform a table to each column as a vector. If you only want tables for select column, run: `lapply(your_data[,c("ColName1", "ColName2")], table)`

Comment: Thank you so much. That solves the problem theoretically, but practically, I am still a long way to go. It seems that if I want to write the subset with the results as a csv, R will not let me by saying that there is a difference in the number of rows. ANy ideas of how I could overcome this?                                                                       All the best      David

Comment: I would suggest asking a new question and providing the desired output.  For instance - how do you want the output file to look?

Answer (score 0):

if you use summary(mydata) it should give you output with the number of times each unique value occurs in each column.

if you use count(mydata$column.name) it will give you the unique values in that column and the frequencies.

you should be able to simply use a tapply across all the columns to get what you want.